# ExcelDNA Evaluate Formula returns ExcelErrorName for custom UDF's

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, excel-interop, excel-dna

I am using ExcelDNA to write custom UDF's in C#, nevertheless this seems to be a general problem with Excel and evaluation of formulas.

My only question: Am I doing anything wrong (maybe wrong UDF definition) or is this a problem with Excel?

Thanks for you help.

=========================================================================

### UDF

Let's say I define a UDF like this:

```
[ExcelFunction(IsMacroType = true, Name = "MyTest")]
public static string MyTest()
{
    return "MyTest";
}
```

### Working

The following formula evaluations are working fine (result "MyTest"):

```
var evaluation = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfEvaluate, "MyTest()");
```

### Not working

Whereas this evaluation does not work (result will be "ExcelErrorName"):

```
var evaluation = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfEvaluate, "CONCAT(MyTest(); MyTest())");
```

I tried out several things and recognized that it is possible to create as many UDF's as you want and also nest them inside each other. But as soon as you pass any two (or more) of your own UDF's as parameters to any other function Excel is unable to evaluate the formula.

I also tried using the Excel interop method which returns the corresponsing COM error:

```
var app = ExcelDnaUtil.Application as Application;
var result = app.Evaluate("CONCAT(MyTest(), MyTest())");
```

### Examples

Working

```
var evaluation = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfEvaluate, "MyTest2(MyTest2(MyTest2()))");
var evaluation = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfEvaluate, "MyTest3(MyTest(); CONCAT(\"A\";\"B\"))");
```

Not working

```
var evaluation = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfEvaluate, "MyTest2(MyTest(); MyTest())");
var evaluation = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfEvaluate, "MyTest2(MyTest(); MyTest3())");
```

Comment: OK - I can reproduce this. The COM error when calling this from VBA is: Error 2029. It might be similar to this bug: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/823604 which seems to relate to the name resolution. Strange that it works if the UDF name is the first parameter ...

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?  I've come up against this same problem recently.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of quirks with Evaluate (see my blog post [about Evaluate](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/) )
Not sure what your CONCAT function is, but this VBA code works OK in XL 2016 for me:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MyTest()
MyTest = "MyTest"
End Function
Public Function MyTest2()
MyTest2 = "MyTest2"
End Function
Public Function MyTest3(var1, var2)
MyTest3 = var1 & var2
End Function
Sub evaltest()
Dim var As Variant
Dim var2 As Variant
var = Evaluate("MyTest3(MyTest(), MyTest2())")
var2 = Evaluate("CONCATENATE(MyTest(), MyTest2())")
End Sub
```

Comment: Does `Evaluate` perhaps require the "," as parameter separator, instead of the user's list separator, which seems to be ";" in this case?

Comment: Evaluate needs US English strings, so presumably this extends to separators

Comment: Ok, if UDF's over VBA are working... Maybe my problem is connected to the way ExcelDNA registers a UDF in Excel?

Comment: @Govert Evaluate needs "," as separator whereas ExcelDNA and XlCall.xlfEvaluate is fine with ";". Already tried that out

Comment: What happens if you use commas and IsMacroType=False?

Comment: @DustinKremer What is "CONCAT"? And can you confirm that "=CONCATENATE(NOW(); NOW())" works?

Comment: @Govert yeah, I meant CONCATENATE and yes, using NOW as parameters works as expected